# Haskell search for anagrams

Tags: haskell

I need help, I need to find all the sets of anagrams that contain the most words.

The function must be of the following type:
anagram :: [String] -> [[String]]

Example:

anagram ["abc", "hehe", "foo", "cba", "eheh", "hhee", "oof", "ofo"]

[["eheh", "hehe", "hhee"], ["foo", "ofo", "oof"]]

It is necessary to use only the data.list library and fit all the code into one line with a maximum length of 104.

```
import Data.List

anagram :: [String] -> [[String]]

anagram lst =  let {t = map (nub. map snd) $ groupBy (\(l,_) (r,_) -> l == r) $ sortOn fst $  map (\s -> (sort s,s)) lst;  cmax = maximum $ map length t} in  filter (\l -> cmax == length l) t
```

The problem is that my code is too long, you can help me, I don't know anything about haskell
I need to put all the code on one line and not exceed 104 characters, my code is placed on one line, but has a length of more than 104

Answer (score 0):

I’m finding your question a little unclear, but it sounds like your problem is that your code is over the line limit. If so, it should just be possible to add line breaks to your code, like this:

```
import Data.List

anagram :: [String] -> [[String]]
anagram lst =
    let t = map (nub. map snd) $
            groupBy (\(l,_) (r,_) -> l == r) $
            sortOn fst $
            map (\s -> (sort s,s)) lst
        cmax = maximum $ map length t
    in filter (\l -> cmax == length l) t
```

I recommend reading [this guide on Haskell indentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation) to learn about code formatting in Haskell.

Comment: no problem is, I need to put all the code on one line and not exceed 104 characters, my code is placed on one line, but has a length of more than 104

Comment: @IvanArtt Hmm, maybe you should edit that into your question? As for how to do that, I’m not sure… I’d suggest that you should first focus on finding a simpler method of solving this problem, and only then try to write some code for it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
anagram = let by f = groupBy (\x y -> f x == f y) . sortOn f in last . by length . by sort
```

Comment: ./checker.sh: line 10:    26 Killed                  timeout --signal=KILL "$timeout" runuser -u nobody -- "$@"

Comment: It works, but for some reason I cannot submit for verification

Comment: although the timeout is set to 1 second, it should work